# Using PBEq in Z3 .Net API

Tags: z3

I have a problem in which I want to be able to pick one (and only one) of many variables. I believe that this can be done through the use of "PBEq" function. But as I am using the .Net API for Z3 I did not find this fucntion in this API. Can some one help me?

Comment: There is Context.MkPBEq(...), is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: This is what I am looking for but I don't have it in the .Net API which I am using.

Comment: It's definitely a recent addition, quite possibly not in the last official release, so you'll have to use either one of our nightly binaries, or build Z3 from source yourself.

Comment: Thanks it did help a lot. and the issue was solved.